# How to fix error: 'AnnAssign' nodes are not implemented in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to do following:

```
import pandas as pd
d = {'col1': [1, 7, 3, 6], 'col2': [3, 4, 9, 1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

out = df.query('col1 > col2')

out=    col1  col2
1     7     4
3     6     1
```

This works OK. But when I modify column name **col1** --> **col1:suf**

```
d = {'col1:suf': [1, 7, 3, 6], 'col2': [3, 4, 9, 1]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    
    out = df.query('col1:suf > col2')
```

I get an error:

> 'AnnAssign' nodes are not implemented

Is there easy way to avoid this behavior? Or course renaming headers etc. is a workaround

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colon `:` is a special character in SQL queries. You need to enclose it in backticks.

Try this :

```
out = df.query('`col1:suf` > col2')
```

Output :

```
print(out)

   col1:suf  col2
1         7     4
3         6     1
```

Answer (score 0):

According to ValentinFFM's comment on [this issue](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/21525), you need to put a backtick quote around your column name like

```
df.query('`Column: Name`==value')
```